letters of recommendation for computer science masters
How does someone secure strong letters of recommendation for a master's program in computer science, considering my bachelor's degree is in biology and I graduated five years ago?

Any reason you asked this separately from your other question?

Securing strong letters of recommendation for a master's program in computer science, especially when coming from a different field and with some time since graduation, involves thoughtful planning and strategic outreach.
If you are approaching a master by course degree in computer science, there is no specific requirements that you must have related CS background. You could reconnect with former professers. Even if you graduated five years ago, you should reach out to professors who knew you well during your undergraduate studies in biology. These letters can highlight your academic abilities, research skills, and dedication to learning, all of which are relevant to any field of study. When reconnecting, remind them of your past work and update them on your career progress and current goals.
If you have any CS/IT related working experiences, you can consider asking for recommendations from supervisors or colleagues who can speak to your technical skills, analytical abilities or any specific CS related projects you have undertaken.
Another personal suggestion is "never asking anyone who is famous in CS but you don't have any connection with". They receive many similar requests everyday and won't waste time for someone they don't know.
